# spark-submit add packages to worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

If I use `spark-submit` with `--packages` and give a maven package, does that package get added to worker nodes, or just the master?

I'm using the `--packages` argument and specifying a single maven dependency. I've gotten a shell to the driver pod and confirmed that the jar is being downloaded to the driver.

However, the worker logs are throwing `ClassNotFoundExceptions` for classes part of this dependency. I expect that the dependency is on the master but not worker nodes.

How can I add this dependency to the worker nodes?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation mention :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

> When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to the cluster. URLs supplied after --jars must be separated by commas. That list is included in the driver and executor classpaths. Directory expansion does not work with --jars.

> Users may also include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list of Maven coordinates with --packages.

Yes the jar will be uploaded to the cluster and therefor all the jvm on the worker nodes.